# Attach Internal Text file to the Gmail

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an android application using kotlin. I am writing application logs into a text file and store into internal storage. I have sent a log button for sending logs. when I click a send log button I will send the stored text file by opening Gmail app but the Gmail returning toast unable to attach file. Here my file provider implementation for sending the text file via Gmail app

Creating a file and writting log like:

```
    fun writeLog(className: String, methodName: String, error: String) {

        var OSName: String = Build.VERSION.RELEASE
        var deviceName: String = Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL
        var time = Calendar.getInstance().time
        var message =
            "OS Name : $OSName, DeviceName : $deviceName, Time : $time, ClassName : $className, MethodName : $methodName, Error : $error"

            val file = File("/data/data/com.deemsysinc.telemedicinecustomer/files/
", "TelemedicineCustomerLog.txt")

        Log.d("Fileres ", "response " + message)
        val directory = File("/data/data/com.deemsysinc.telemedicinecustomer/files/")

        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir()
        }

        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile()
            } catch (e: Error) {
                Log.d("FileError ", "error " + e.toString())
            }
        }
        try {
            file.writeText(message)
        } catch (e: Error) {
            Log.d("FileError ", "error " + e.toString())
        }
}
```

Sending Email Like

```
var path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(self,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".fileprovider",file)
Log.d("NewFileUriPath",""+path)
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:" + "Support@telemedicinecustomer.com")
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,path)
if (intent.resolveActivity(self.packageManager) != null) {
    self.startActivity(intent)
} else {
    Toast.makeText(
        self,
        "You have not installed gmail app",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()
}
```

xml/provider_path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="/" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.deemsysinc.telemedicinecustomer.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
</provider>
```

Is this correct way to implement file provider for attaching text file to Gmail?

Comment: "Creating a file and writting log like" -- **never hardcode paths**. Also, don't just eat the errors. Your code that is calling `writeLog()` needs to know if it succeeds or fails. "Sending Email Like" -- `ACTION_SENDTO` is not documented to support `EXTRA_STREAM`. Try `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: its not working. returning error like you have not installed Gmail app

Comment: If you are still using `intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:" + "Support@telemedicinecustomer.com")`, you would need to switch that to `EXTRA_EMAIL`. `ACTION_SENDTO` does not use a `Uri`.